# Retrieve a row associated with an id in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm building a mobile app with angularjs and run into a strange problem.

I have a request which retrieves a `book` object. In that request there is a field named `book_category` which contains the id of the category this `book` belongs too.

I want to build up one another request to retrieve the `category` associated with that `book_category` to be able to map the `book_category` to a name, instead of just a number. A simple SQL JOIN-like operation.

So I've made my controller like this:

```
booksControllers.controller('BookDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Book', 'Category',
    function($scope, $routeParams, Book, Category) {
        var book = Book.get({id: $routeParams.bookId});
        $scope.book = book;
        $scope.category = Category.get({categoryId: book.book_category});
}]);
```

and my service is like:

```
var booksServices = angular.module('booksServices', ['ngResource']);

booksServices.factory('Book', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://****.herokuapp.com/books/:id.json', {}, {});
}]);

booksServices.factory('Category', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://****.herokuapp.com/categories/:categoryId.json', {}, {});
}]);
```

The problem is that I get an error that AngularJS is expecting an object but has got an array. That's because angularjs sends a request to `categories.json` instead of something like `categories/<id>.json`, which it's supposed to do, because I provide the required `categoryId` to it.

Is there any workaround to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the requests are asynchronous.

The `Book.get()` call itself will not return a populated object, just an empty reference object which gets populated later, (see [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)). As such, when you make a call to `Categories.get()` immediately afterwards, you're supplying an empty object for the `id`.

The docs also suggest that the resource objects have a `$promise` field, which gets resolved when the query does.

As such, you should be able to do this:

```
// Hook into the promise from the previous API call
book.$promise.then( function() {
  // This code gets run when the book object gets populated.
  $scope.category = Category.get({categoryId: book.book_category});
});
```

I can't test it without a plunkr, and I've never used `$resource`, so let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks Ed. I had guessed that it could be asynchronous, but couldn't figure out how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

get is an async function that needs to be called with a callback. You can do something like that:

```
Book.get({id: $routeParams.bookId}, function(book) {
    $scope.book = book;
    Category.get({categoryId: book.book_category}, function(category) {
        // do something with category
    });
);
```

See documentation of $resource [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource).